# Liquibase generateChangeLog not including column length (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase's generateChangeLog command as follows:

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --classpath=$HOME/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.26/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar \
  --changeLogFile=./db.changelog.xml \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" \
  generateChangeLog
```

Which outputs XML change log without column length definitions for all columns.

Example:

```
<changeSet author="purecharger (generated)" id="1461081110463-2">
    <createTable tableName="account">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        ...
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Column Definition (snippet):

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  ...
```

Why doesn't the changelog include length, like so?

```
<column name="id" type="BIGINT(20)">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

Comment: Is length implied by BIGINT datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, BIGINT specifies 8 bytes of space, which is enough for integers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. BIGINT(20) doesn't really mean anything. MySQL is being generous by accepting it.

Full details at this MySQL page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Good point, but why doesn't liquibase not output the precision if thats what mysql shows?

Comment: Very good question. Seems strange to me if the MySQL tools keep track of that. What Liquibase does is use the JDBC driver to query the table and column metadata. I haven't debugged through the code, but I imagine that the JDBC driver either isn't returning the size data, that Liquibase isn't looking for size data, or that Liquibase purposely throws away the size data.